# PHP access property of individual method inside object

Tags: php, function, oop, object

Trying to get the property inside a function so not sure how to do it.
Here is my class:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Data extends CI_Controller {

   public $data;

   public function __construct()    {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->model('months');
       $this->load->driver('cache');

   }
}

public function graph1() {

    $this->data = $this->months->get_months();
    $this->layout->view('graph1', $this->data);
}
```

So trying to get value of $data inside graph1() in another class, for example:

```
$object = new Data();
print_r($object->data);
```

This gives me a blank output, how can i make the $data value have the database result set?

Comment: You should call `$object->graph1()` before asking for `$object->data` ?

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata it does nothing to call $object->graph1(). Any other ideas? And why did someone down vote this answer? It fulfills all requirements of a question. Once again ppl can't answer the questions I post and i get a downvote... so wrong

Comment: I mean you are calling `$object->data` but the object should not hold any result yet, because the data is only assigned when you call `graph1` function. On Stackoverflow, you're expected to ask questions that apply not just to you alone but to others too.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata this question applies to anyone trying to do unit testing of a function that sends data to a layout. Part of the unit testing is to see if what $data sends to layout is correct. So again, its incredible that i get downvoted for asking a question. I realize $data is not populated yet but that is part of the question, "how can i make the $data value have the database result set?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before dumping your object data, call your graph method to actually get the data. i.e.

```
$object = new Data();
$object->graph1();
print_r($object->data);
```

You could also call `graph1` from your constructor like:

```
public function __construct()    {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('months');
   $this->load->driver('cache');
   $this->graph1();
}
```

That way you would be able to actually use:

```
$object = new Data();
print_r($object->data);
```

If this solves your problem, I suggest you should read up [OOP concepts](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762). Regards.

Comment: This is a web application so if i call graph1() inside the constructor the web application will break as it will be sending incorrect data to the layout. The reason i wanted to extract it from the graph1() directly is so i don't mess up the layout, below is a solution that works with a layout. So read and don't hate please.

Answer (score -4):

I will show the real solution that works with the web application and unit testing.

Change this on data controller to:

```
public function graph1() {

   $this->data = $this->months->get_months();
   $this->layout->view('graph1', $this->data);
```

}

To:

```
public function graph1() {

   $this->data = $this->months->get_months();
   $this->layout->view('graph1', $this->data);
   return $this->data;
}
```

The return won't cause problems with the layout and views. And will return the correct data to the unit test:

```
public function testgraph1() {      

    $object = new Data();

    $out = $object->graph1();
    print_r($out);

    $this->assertArrayHasKey('11', $out);
}
```

So the other answer is incorrect, and will cause issues with the layout when `graph1()` is called in  the constructor. I don't need to read about OOP but would suggest the person who answered incorrectly to read about web applications and unit testing.